# css select elements with style rule set by external style sheet

Tags: html, css

With css you can use

```
    [style="cursor:pointer"] {cursor:wait;}
```

but this only works if the style rule in set inline.
I want to do this when the style rule is set by an external style sheet.

[here](https://codepen.io/Beck-Busch/pen/PmRdvg) is a heavily commented codepen example. Thanks guys.

Edit: It is important to know that I can not edit the html or the external stylesheet(The first style rule in my example) I can only inject a stylesheet.

Comment: In your CodePen you write: "This code [...] works on the inline button but I want it to work on the style sheet button." You are not targeting the Style Sheet button. Are you asking how to target it?

Comment: I don't believe there is any style that works inline but not in a stylesheet, although the inverse is true. This probably means there is a problem with your stylesheet.

Comment: @LeoGalleguillos I don't want a style, I want a selector

Comment: @Corey I want to select the style sheet button, only because it is styled by the first rule. I want a one size fits all for styling buttons that are already styled a certain way by an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code above works as expected, due to the fact that changes to elements through CSS don't actually 'manipulate' the elements themselves, but rather their appearance. Essentially, CSS attributes only look at the DOM. Let me break it down for you:

You have two elements on the page, both `<input>`. The first input is styled inline with `style="cursor:pointer"`. You then have the following two components of CSS:

```
div [type="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[style="cursor:pointer"] {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```

The first input skips over the first rule, as it is not inside a `<div>`. it then has the second rule applied, as it is styled as a pointer cursor **on page load** (because it is inline).

The second element applies the first rule, as it is inside a `<div>`. You might expect that due to CSS reading from top-to-bottom, that it would apply the second rule as well. This is not the case, as the CSS `cursor` attribute change is applied through a **CSS rule**, and is **not** present on page load. Thus, when the CSS file is loaded, it still reads it as a regular cursor, rather than a pointer cursor.

If you change the second style to:

```
input {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```

You will see the second element correctly apply the `wait` cursor. This is because the second element was **already** an input when the CSS rules started to apply.

If you'd like to style a certain group of buttons with the `wait` cursor, while excluding other buttons, the best way to handle this is with a `class`:

```
.wait {
  cursor: wait;
}

<input type="button" class="wait">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You gave a perfect answer to the wrong question and that is my fault. I understand what is going on with the css, I did it that way for an example. I want to apply the 2nd css rule to the style sheet button, selecting it _because_ of the first rule and overriding the first rule. this is an example. IN the real scenario, I would have no control over the first rule or the html. does this make any sense?

Comment: Ahh, I get you now; my apologies :)  The best way to overwrite a particular style is to add more specificity. Unfortunately your HTML doesn't have much to work with in that regard, but you can do something like `body div input`. If you have any IDs or classes, you can make use of those :) Though due to the fact that `!important` gives maximum specificity, you won't be able to override that unfortunately!

Comment: Thanks so much.  I will try to find a solution but I want to know, is there a way to select elements by external css rules like there is for inline rules?

Comment: No, because the style rule is not part of the DOM. If it helps, there is going to be *something* about buttons with a pointer cursor that will be targetable. I can't think of a reason why you'd need to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: CSS rules apply to the same elements, whether the rules are written in the same file or an external stylesheet. The only difference is load order. Inline styles are written slightly differently, and have **higher specificity**. The **only** way you can override inline styles is with `!important`. You should be able to edit some of the HTML or CSS in order to get around the `!important` declaration though -- I can't see why you'd be developing a website if you couldn't touch either the HTML or CSS ;)

Comment: @Corey yes! Exactly. This is my point. There _is_ something targetable about buttons, the rule `[type="button"]{cursor:pointer;}` the only problem is that this rule is nearly always in an external style sheet so you can't target it like you can target inline rules. This is what I tried to show in my example. I want to know how to target it when the rule is set by an external style sheet.

Comment: Not the rule, the target. We know or should know that all `div [type="button"]` elements will have a pointer cursor. So target `div [type="button"]`.